Hoppscotch Pre-request Script async request
I'm experiencing an issue with the asynchronous execution order of .then() in a fetch request within my JavaScript script. The script is supposed to fetch an authentication token and then set it in an environment variable. However, it seems like the URL call for my application is happening before the .then() chains execute, leading to the use of an unset token. I need the token to be retrieved and set before making a subsequent request. So it successfully retrieves the token and the script is being executed until the first part of fetch, but before the .then it calls the url and then executes the rest of the script.
const authUrl = "https://auth0.com/oauth/token";
const authBody = JSON.stringify({
  grant_type: "password",
  client_id: "client_id",
  client_secret: "client_secret",
  scope: "openid profile email",
  audience: "https://audience/",
  username: "username",
  password: "password"
});
console.log("nach dem ziehen des token")
// Execute the fetch request to authenticate
fetch(authUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: authBody
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  if (data.access_token) {
    // Set the access token in an environment variable
    pw.env.set("accessToken", data.access_token);
        pw.env.set("accessToken", data.access_token);
    console.log("accessToken set:", data.access_token); // to check the log
  } else {
    console.error('Error retrieving the token:', data);
  }
})
.catch(error => console.error('Error in fetching auth token:', error));


How did you avoid the [semantic] Unknown identifier 'fetch' in the script?

@RaffaeleLungarella I dont get a Unknown identifier 'fetch' for the script, maybe it is related to the browser? I am using Chrome

I get it from every browser and even with the desktop app. I am quite confused since there is this issue on their github repo: https://github.com/hoppscotch/hoppscotch/issues/3305. It seems like this feature does not exist and yet you are using it. Am I reading something wrong?

I am still using the pre-request script below and it works fine. I am using it for a single request and after I have made that request, I can use the <<access_token>> in other requests aswell as it says here https://docs.hoppscotch.io/documentation/getting-started/rest/pre-request-scripts

I solved this issue by declaring a function and the calling that function at the end:
const authUrl = pw.env.get("auth0_url")+"/oauth/token";
const authBody = JSON.stringify({
  grant_type: "password",
  client_id: pw.env.get("client_id"),
  client_secret: pw.env.get("client_secret"),
  scope: "openid profile email",
  audience: pw.env.get("audience"),
  username: pw.env.get("username_auth0"),
  password: pw.env.get("password_auth0"),
});

function authenticate() {
  try {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", authUrl, false);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.send(authBody);

    if (request.status === 200) {
      const data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      if (data.access_token) {
        pw.env.set("accessToken", data.access_token);
        console.log("accessToken set:", data.access_token); 
        // Zusätzlich überprüfen, ob es korrekt gesetzt wurde
        let token = pw.env.get("accessToken");
        console.log("Retrieved accessToken:", token);
      } else {
        console.error('Error retrieving the token:', data);
        pw.env.set("accessToken", "");
      }
    } else {
      console.error('Error in fetching auth token. Status:', request.status);
      pw.env.set("accessToken", "");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in fetching auth token:', error);
    pw.env.set("accessToken", "");
  }
}

// Funktion aufrufen, um die Authentifizierung durchzuführen
authenticate();



are you sure, you are not getting CORS error. I am asking this because, in hoppscotch if the env variable is set once, it lives there afterwards. So, by any chance if you have fill the accessToken it will stay there and you would note notice it until it expires.
you can verify by looking in console F12.

Yes, the access token is valid until i change it, but I don't get a Cors error.

I returned to this problem after a while, and your solution worked just fine. I wanted to point out to future people who try to make this work that the [semantic] Unknown identifier 'XMLHttpRequest()' is a false negative.
